# The problem with installing pyaudio

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit

I want to install `pyaudio` on my RPi 4 that has 64bit Bullseye 11.2.

According to https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/8/23/recording-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-python-and-a-usb-microphone I should do

```
sudo apt install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev
```

however I get

```
E: Unable to locate package libportaudio0
```

pyaudio actually recognises my I2S microphone

```
snd_rpi_i2s_card: simple-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 (hw:1,0)
```

but reading sound from it goes nowhere.

I know this worked on 32-bit rRspberry Pi OS. Is this a 64-bit OS problem? How to solve it?

Comment: It looks like you followed the suggestions at the top of that thread, which were written 9+ years ago.   I would try the updated suggestions at the bottom, which are much newer.

Comment: @goldilocks Later instruction actually install less packages.  But it does not work..  BTW, newer sites also use the same instructions: https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/8/23/recording-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-python-and-a-usb-microphone

Comment: *"I know this worked on 32bit raspberry OS"* -> There's no `libportaudio0` in the 64-bit version whereas there is in the "oldstable" buster (v10) 32-bit.  "oldstable" means imported from the previous release, stretch (v9).

Comment: I notice there is a `python-pyaudio` package in buster oldstable as well -- **but including  64-bit.**  Have you tried that? It should pull in dependencies for you, unless the package is broken.  `apt show python-pyaudio` on buster 64-bit gives `libportaudio2` <- 2 not 0, which should be available.

Comment: @goldilocks I am sorry I don't understand you completely.  I was able to install `libportaudio2`.  The problem is that it is not working.  The pyaudio recognises I2S microphone, but never finishes `while _stream.get_read_available() < sampnumb`.

Comment: @goldilocks Maybe there is problem elsewhere, because sometimes (<5%) it actually works.  Maybe the whole thing is unstable on 64bit platform.  In your opinion `libportaudio0` not essential?  I don't understand anything, just following instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libportaudio0`, `libportaudio2`, `libportaudiocpp0` are/were essentially just dependencies on the `portaudio19-dev` package.  But over time `libportaudio0` has stopped being a dependency and is no longer needed (source: http://packages.debian.org/bullseye/portaudio19-dev)

Also, since installing the `portaudio19-dev` package automatically installs the dependencies, one only needs to run

```
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev
```

If one just runs this command, everything should work normally.

Comment: I confirm installing that allows for a smooth pip3 install pyaudio. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that `libportaudio` is not available in the 64-bit RpiOS.

The deeper problem is that the advice you have been following is perhaps not very good -- I won't say definitely, because I'm not a user of pyaudio, but it smells like it a bit.  My major reason for suspecting this is that there is a `python-pyaudio` package available in 64 (and 32) -bit, and has been [at least since buster](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-pyaudio&searchon=names&suite=oldstable&section=all) and most likely for a long time before that.

Yet the article you link does not mention this even once, which implies the author was not aware and did not have a good understanding of linux package management systems.  The python module is `pyaudio`, so if it is available in the distro, very likely that is in the package name, and in fact there is a simple logic that can be observed in python package names such that we might assume this package is most likely called `python-pyaudio`.  But let's just search for pyaudio first:

```
> apt search pyaudio
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python-pyaudio/oldstable 0.2.11-1+b2 arm64
  Python bindings for PortAudio v19

python-pyaudio-doc/oldstable,oldstable 0.2.11-1 all
  Documentation for Python bindings for PortAudio v19

python3-pyaudio/oldstable 0.2.11-1+b2 arm64
  Python3 bindings for PortAudio v19
```

There are a couple more packages in the list returned that I have left off.
It is interesting that these are in `oldstable` and not the `stable`; this is a buster system so it means that package has been there since stretch, which is going back 4-5 years.<sup>1</sup> The version listed here is explicitly for "PortAudio v19", which if we [dig into their website](http://www.portaudio.com) a bit reveals that this is the current version.

*It is important to understand that if the package manager installs something in its default mode, that software is ready to use.  A major purpose of a package management system is that it manages dependencies for you.*

There is both a python and python3 package available.  Here's more about the latter:

```
> apt show python3-pyaudio
Package: python3-pyaudio
Version: 0.2.11-1+b2
Priority: optional
Section: python
Source: python-pyaudio (0.2.11-1)
Maintainer: Hubert Pham <hubert@mit.edu>
Installed-Size: 148 kB
Provides: python3.6-pyaudio, python3.7-pyaudio
Depends: python3 (<< 3.8), python3 (>= 3.6~), python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~), libc6 (>= 2.17), libportaudio2 (>= 19+svn20101113)
Suggests: python-pyaudio-doc (>= 0.2.11)
Homepage: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
Download-Size: 25.3 kB
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 Packages
Description: Python3 bindings for PortAudio v19
```

There are dependencies there including `libportaudio2`, which presumably replaced `libportaudio0`.  Again: **You do not have to go through the list of dependencies and install them all one at a time manually.** By installing `python[3]-pyaudio`, those dependencies will be included.

So, what you should have tried **first** was just:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyaudio
```

Presuming you want the python3 version.  I can't promise this does work, but  it is not hard to try.

---

1. Meaning it was there when that article was written.  This is actually good, since it implies that all the rigmarole there was not because the pyaudio package was broken but because the author was not aware it existed.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try your suggestion.  Should I first uninstall `libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev`?  As I am using python2, I guess I need `python-pyaudio`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that; if there is some conflict or problem with having package A and package B at the same time, the package manager will tell you when you go to install package B (presuming you already have A installed).  Just note that does not cover things installed some other way (eg. from source or via `pip`).  WRT which package, yes, `python-pyaudio` is the one for python 2.

Comment: What I don't understand, in my naivety, is how python program knows which package to use, `libportaudio2` or `python-pyaudio`?

Comment: `libportaudio2` is a compiled shared library not written in python, as PortAudio is not python centric.  Many python modules include bits written in C, so that non-python libraries can be used; that's what part of the `pyaudio` module does.  WRT the python interpreter, it will use the `pyaudio` module installed by the distro package `python-pyaudio`, but it does not know about or make use of the distro package manager.  Ie., `libportaudio2` is the actual system library binary, `pyaudio` uses that under-the-hood, and `python-pyaudio` is the distro package that includes the `pyaudio` module.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get error `E: Unable to locate package python-pyaudio`

Comment: It must be bullseye then; I'm still using buster 64-bit -- sorry about that.  If they've removed the package for whatever reason, that reason is very possibly one that will make it impossible for you to do it another way.

Comment: I realised that installing `portaudio19-dev` works.  Installation also picks packages that this package depends on, like `libportaudio2` or `libportaudiocpp0` (source: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/portaudio19-dev).  `portaudio19-dev` no longer depends on `libportaudio`.  Will you edit your reply or shall I answer my question myself?

Comment: If it works now, go ahead and answer it yourself; I am not really a pyaudio user after all.   I got cut off by the maintenance outage yesterday but I was going to observe it is strange these packages aren't in RpiOS 11 since they are in Debian bullseye for arm64: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-pyaudio  Might have something to do with some of the dependencies, I think they include some Wayland stuff that may not work on the Pi but wouldn't actually affect the audio system.   So they just left it all out, perhaps.